# Memory allocation and working of std::map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I was reading about the map c++ dictionary implementation. I read a code somewhere on the net which had the following lines.

```
map <int, int> A[100005];
A[1][2]=1;
```

please can you explain how is memory allocated. Is it in the same way as a 2-D array or it increases dynamically while we are inserting.

And how does the insertion in the map takes place given the second line of code.

Comment: Any documentation on `std::map` should explain how it works (what it does), and a reference on `operator[]` will easily give the semantics.

Comment: Please note that what you have in your example is an *array* of maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `std::map` is typically a self balancing binary search tree<sup>1</sup>. This is a node-based data structure, quite different to an array. Typically, the data are allocated dynamically. What you have here:

```
map <int, int> A[100005];
```

is an array of maps with automatic storage, so a plain array of 100005 binary search trees that gets destroyed when exiting the scope in which it is declared.

So this

```
A[1][2]=1;
```

is adding a key-value pair (2,1) to the second map in the array.

<sup>The C++ standard does not specify how exactly an `std::map` should be implemented, but places conditions on complexity of various operations, and iterator validity, which mean that it really is implemented as a self-balancing BST, typically a [**red-black tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You example would more easy to explain with that code:

```
map <int, int> A[100005];
A[1][2]=3; // change: 3 instead of 1, at the right side of the =
```

The first line create an array of size 100005 on the stack (automatic storage), and the elements of the array are of type `map<int, int>`. A `map` is an object that allocates dynamically (on the heap) a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) with `pair<int, int>` at the nodes. It also enforce that each pair as a different first component (that is the difference with `std::multimap`). `A[1]` is the second map in the array (because indices of array start at 0), and `A[1][2]=3` is equivalent to `A[1].operator(2)=3` A map `m` of type `std::map<X,Y>` stores a mapping between elements of type `X` and `Y`. Given a `X x`, then `m[x]` gives a reference to an object of type `Y`. See the [documentation of `map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). In your case, `X` and `Y` are `int`. To conclude, `A[1][2]=3` take the second map `A[1]` of the array and stores `3` in the reference `A[1][2]` that is returned by `A[1].map<int,int>::operator[](2)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think the fact that `A` is a static array is confusing you. Have a look at this example:

```
map <int, int> A;
A[2]=1;
```

Nothing special about it right? Now if you come back to the original case and figure that `A[1]` is simply a map in the array you will see it is not much different.